# How can I match nested brackets using regex?

Tags: regex, nested

As the title says, here is an example input:

```
 (outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer)
 (outer
   (inner)
 ouer)
 (outer
 ouer)
```

Of course, the matched strings will be processed by recursion.

I want the first recursion to match:

```
 [
 (outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer),
 (outer
   (inner)
 ouer),
 (outer
 ouer)]
```

And the after processes is needless to say...

Comment: Well, that would be terribly inefficient to repeatedly parse brackets like that. Use a real parser. (A counter with a character-by-character loop will suffice).

Comment: Looks like you need something like lisp there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Many regex implementations will not allow you to match an arbitrary amount of nesting. However, Perl, PHP and .NET support recursive patterns.

A demo in Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $text = '(outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer)
 (outer
   (inner)
 ouer)
 (outer
 ouer)';

while($text =~ /(\(([^()]|(?R))*\))/g) {
  print("----------\n$1\n");
}
```

which will print:

```
----------
(outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer)
----------
(outer
   (inner)
 ouer)
----------
(outer
 ouer)
```

Or, the PHP  equivalent:

```php
$text = '(outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer)
 (outer
   (inner)
 ouer)
 (outer
 ouer)';

preg_match_all('/(\(([^()]|(?R))*\))/', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

which produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (outer
   (center
     (inner)
     (inner)
   center)
 ouer)
            [1] => (outer
   (inner)
 ouer)
            [2] => (outer
 ouer)
        )

...
```

An explanation:

```
(          # start group 1
  \(       #   match a literal '('
  (        #   group 2
    [^()]  #     any char other than '(' and ')'
    |      #     OR
    (?R)   #     recursively match the entir pattern
  )*       #   end group 2 and repeat zero or more times
  \)       #   match a literal ')'
)          # end group 1
```

### EDIT

Note @Goozak's comment:

> A better pattern might be `\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)` (from [PHP:Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)). For my data, Bart's pattern was crashing PHP when it encountered a (long string) without nesting. This pattern went through all my data without problem.

Comment: @Goozak, note that I often post regex patterns as easy as possible so that it is easier to understand. But you are right, it could optimized quite a bit by the atomic group, and greedy matching of `[^()]`. I'll edit my answer with your comment.

Comment: @BartKiers, my use of the phrase "better pattern" may have been too strong. :-)  I tried your pattern and found that it crashed with my data.  When I found that the PHP help pattern went through, I just wanted to mention it here in case others found themselves in the same situation.  This definitely wasn't a disparaging comment on your original pattern.

Comment: No problem! You raise a valid point: on large input, my original pattern does not performs well :)

Comment: Actually this does not work if there is an escaped bracket in between. Any Idea how to fix that? `((foo)bar\)baz\\)` (I am trying to parse a RegEx string with RegEx... thats why I have to respect escaped characters aswell :-()

Comment: @boesing instead of `[^()]`, do `(?:[^\\()]|\\[\\()])`

Comment: RE: .Net support, this post led me to discover `balancing groups` - a way of capturing content between open and close brackets/tags that copes with any nested content.  Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing-group-definitions

Answer (score 27):

Don't use regex.

Instead, a simple recursive function will suffice. Here's the general structure:

```
def recursive_bracket_parser(s, i):
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == '(':
            i = recursive_bracket_parser(s, i+1)
        elif s[i] == ')':
            return i+1
        else:
            # process whatever is at s[i]
            i += 1
    return i
```

For example, here's a function that will parse the input into a nested list structure:

```
def parse_to_list(s, i=0):
    result = []
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == '(':
            i, r = parse_to_list(s, i+1)
            result.append(r)
        elif s[i] == ')':
            return i+1, result
        else:
            result.append(s[i])
            i += 1
    return i, result
```

Calling this like `parse_to_list('((a) ((b)) ((c)(d)))efg')` produces the result `[[['a'], ' ', [['b']], ' ', [['c'], ['d']]], 'e', 'f', 'g']`.

Comment: A usage example would be handy.

Answer (score 10):

I found this simple regex which extracts all nested balanced groups using recursion, although the resulting solution is not quite straightforward as you may expect:

Regex pattern: `(1(?:\1??[^1]*?2))+`

Sample input: `1ab1cd1ef2221ab1cd1ef222`

For simplicity I put `1` for open and `2` for closed bracket. Alpha characters represent some inner data.
I'll rewrite input so that it can be easy to explain.

> ```
> 1  ab  1 cd 1ef2 2  2     1  ab  1 cd 1ef2 2  2
>
>             |_1|
>        |______2__|
> |_____________3_____|
> ```

In first iteration regex will match the most inner subgroup `1ef2` of in first sibling group `1ab1cd1ef222`. If we remember it and it's position, and remove this group, there would remain `1ab1cd22`. If we continue with regex, it would return `1cd2`, and finally `1ab2`. Then, it will continue to parse second sibling group the same way.

As we see from this example, regex will properly extract substrings as they appear in the hierarchy defined by brackets. Position of particularly substring in hierarchy will be determined during second iteration, if it's position in string is between substring from second iteration, then it is a child node, else it's a sibling node.

From our example:

1. `1ab1cd1ef222 1ab1cd1ef222`, iteration match `1ef2`, with index `6`,
2. `1ab1cd22 1ab1cd1ef222`, iteration match `1cd2`, with index `3`, ending with `6`.
   Because `3` < `6` <= `6`, first substring is child of the second substring.
3. `1ab2 1ab1cd1ef222`, iteration match `1ab2`, with index `0`, ending with `3`.
   Because `0` < `3` <= `3`, first substring is child of the second substring.
4. `1ab1cd1ef222`, iteration match `1ef2`, with index `6`,
   Because it's not `3` < `0` <= `6`, it's branch from another sibling, etc...

We must iterate and remove all siblings before we can move to the parent. Thus, we must remember all that siblings in the order they appear in iteration.

Comment: I've been looking all night for this solution. It's the only useful one I found. the 'translated' regexp I ended up using was `(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))`

Comment: @Quonux, that could very well be, I use the above regexp in a PHP program, works like a charm

Comment: If is available a way to process/compare the indexes, its no point in using regex for obtaining them .

Answer (score 0):

**Delphi Pascal code based on posting above from [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo):**

You need a form with a button on it, named btnRun. In the source code, replace "arnolduss" with your name in the DownLoads folder.  Note the stack level in the output created by ParseList.  Obviously brackets of the same type must open and close on the same stack level. You will now be able to extract the so-called groups per stack level.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

Type TCharPos = record
  Level: integer;
  Pos: integer;
  Char: string;
end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnRun: TButton;
    procedure btnRunClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure FormulaFunctionParser(var CharPos: array of TCharPos;
       const formula, LBracket, RBracket: string; var itr, iChar,
       iLevel: integer; var ParseList: TStringList);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnRunClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  formula: string;
  CharPos: array of TCharPos;
  itr, iChar, iLevel: integer;
  ParseList: TStringList;
begin
  screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  itr := 0;
  iChar := 1;
  iLevel := 0;
  ParseList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    formula := Trim('add(mul(a,add(b,c)),d) + e - sub(f,g)');
    ParseList.Add(formula);
    ParseList.Add('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890');

    SetLength(CharPos, Length(formula));
    FormulaFunctionParser(CharPos[0], formula, '(', ')', itr, iChar, iLevel, ParseList);
  finally
    ParseList.SaveToFile('C:\Users\arnolduss\Downloads\ParseList.txt');
    FreeAndNil(ParseList);
    screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;

//Based on code from nneonneo in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex
procedure TForm1.FormulaFunctionParser(var CharPos: array of TCharPos;
       const formula, LBracket, RBracket: string; var itr, iChar,
       iLevel: integer; var ParseList: TStringList);
  procedure UpdateCharPos;
  begin
    CharPos[itr-1].Level := iLevel;
    CharPos[itr-1].Pos := itr;
    CharPos[itr-1].Char := formula[iChar];

    ParseList.Add(IntToStr(iLevel) + '  ' + intToStr(iChar) + ' = ' + formula[iChar]);
  end;
begin
  while iChar <= length(formula) do
  begin
    inc(itr);
    if formula[iChar] = LBracket then
    begin
      inc(iLevel);
      UpdateCharPos;
      inc(iChar);
      FormulaFunctionParser(CharPos, formula, LBracket, RBracket, itr, iChar, iLevel, ParseList);
    end
    else
    if formula[iChar] = RBracket then
    begin
      UpdateCharPos;
      dec(iLevel);
      inc(iChar);
    end
    else
    begin
      UpdateCharPos;
      inc(iChar);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```