# PHP: get array with preg_* functions

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match-all

I want to parser and get a two-dimensional matrix using regular expresions of PHP. But I really don't know to parser and get a array(unidimensional). For example, I have this string:

```
    $str = {a}&{b}&{c}&{d&};
```

and I want to convert to array like this:

```
    array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd&' )
```

The pattern should be this:

```
    $pattern = '#(({[^}]+})(?:&(?1))*#';
```

The pattern matches correctly but I can't get all elements with $matches parameter:

```
    preg_match_all( $pattern, $str, $matches );
    print_r( $matches );
```

Output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => {a}&{b}&{c}&{d&}
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
            )

    )
```

I try to solve this problem involving the recursive pattern with parentheses.

```
    $pattern = '#(({[^}]+})(?:&((?1)))*#';
```

Output:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => {a}&{b}&{c}&{d&}
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => a
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => d&
            )

    )
```

Only is gotten the last element of array. The option flags PREG_PATTERN_ORDER or con PREG_SET_ORDER haven't solved my problem.

Is there any way to get the array of elements?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: Just use the pattern that's been used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740/) like this [`\{((?:[^{}]|(?R))*)\}`](http://regex101.com/r/eN8gV4), it will even match nested `{}` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern which captures the content inside curly brackets and checks the syntax *(i.e. `{..}&{..}&{..}&{..}`)* :

```
preg_match_all('~\G{([^}]+)}(?:&|$)~', '{a}&{b}&{c}&{d&}', $result);
```

`\G` means "contiguous to a precedent match or at the start of the string". Thus, gaps are not allowed and the syntax is checked by the pattern.

The array you are looking for is `$result[1]`

Comment: Oh, thanks! this works. I should review the issue escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, your regex is way overcomplicated.

```
$pattern = "#{([^}]+)}#";
$data = "{a}&{b}&{c}&{d&}";
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {a}
            [1] => {b}
            [2] => {c}
            [3] => {d&}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d&
        )

)
```

So your desired output is just `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Then, should I do two passes to parse $data? Because $data = "{a}|{b}&{c}|{d&}"; is a string succesful. After, I should check '&' characters.

Answer (score 0):

for your former question, try:

```
$str = "a&b&c&d&word";
$pattern = '/[^&]+/';
preg_match_all( $pattern, $str, $matches );
print_r( $matches );
```

get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => word
        )
)
```