# Format a .c file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

An interview question I read:

> Let's say you're on my team, and I've decided I'm a real stickler for
>   code formatting. But I've got peculiar tastes, and one day I decide I
>   want to have all parentheses stand out very clearly in your code.
>
> So let's say you've got a set of source files in C, C++, or Java. Your
>   choice. And I want you to modify them so that in each source file,
>   every open- and close-parenthesis has exactly one space character
>   before and after it. If there is any other whitespace around the
>   parenthesis, it's collapsed into a single space character.

For instance, this code:

```
foo (bar ( new Point(x, graph.getY()) ));
```

Would be modified to look like this:

```
foo ( bar ( new Point ( x, graph.getY ( ) ) ) );
```

How to do this with sed ?

**EDIT**
my approach

```
sed -Ee 's/([()])([()])([()])/\1 \2 \3 /g' -e 's/([ ]{1,}|^|([0-9a-zA-Z()]))([()])([ ]{1,}|$|([0-9;a-z()]))/\2 \3 \5/g'  filename.c
```

This fails at cases like `func(a);` my code outputs it as `func ( a);`

Comment: This interview question shows the ignorance of the interviewer. REs cannot  balance parentheses or count characters (like `"`, so as to know if you are inside or outside a C string for example), so you would end up changing spaces around parentheses also inside strings. If you use RE to accomplish this task you are bound to fail.

Comment: @mescalinum assume that parenthesis are absent in a C string then how do we solve this and how pass cases where my code fails

Comment: Of course they can ever since introduction of [recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) and [balanced groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

Comment: then how would you check if a parenthesis is inside a c string " (" or '('

Comment: [Here is a good start.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740/2016221) note that sed is centuries behind PCRE so you'll need perl or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**: You need to reduce leading and trailing spaces to exactly one independently of each other:

```
$ cat par.sed
s/[[:space:]]*\([()]\)/ \1/g
s/\([()]\)[[:space:]]*/\1 /g
$ sed -i.bak -f par.sed filename.c
```

Easier to understand script:

```
# Collapse leading spaces:
s/ *(/ (/g
s/ *)/ )/g
# Collapse trailing spaces:
s/( */( /g
s/) */) /g
```

Comment: your code creates two spaces in the given test case
(__)__)__)__)

Comment: I just noticed another thing: My example is now correct as to the quoted assignment, but will not be correct as to your example: In your example output there is no space between the last closing parenthesis and the semicolon. But I don't see such a restriction in the assignment, and I haven't implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e "/[\"']/ b" -e '
s/[[:blank:]]*\([()]\)[[:blank:]]*/ \1 /g
:cycle
s/\([()]\)[[:blank:]]\{2,\}\([()]\)/\1 \2/g;t cycle
s/) ;/);/' YourFile
```

- first test to skip line with `"` or `'`, a bit harder (long code) to treat (optional)
- treat the special `;` after a `)`
- use of class `blank` and not `space` for use of tab ansd space char only and not other case like NL, FF, VT, CR  (normaly not necessary because we treat here 1 line a t a time but in c, you could have instruction on several line, so if you want to extend )

Adaptation for space inbetween (thanks to @User112638726 for this remark)

Comment: This leaves multiple blanks inbetweeen adjacent brackets

Comment: @User112638726 right, forget the `g` occur only to next occurence so one change/pattern is excluded from following search. Code adapted for this

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
echo "foo (bar ( new Point(x, graph.getY()) ));" | sed -r 's/([^ ])\(/\1 \(/g; s/([^ ])\)/\1 \)/g; s/\(([^ ])/\( \1/g; s/\)([^ ])/\) \1/g'
```

output
    foo ( bar ( new Point ( x, graph.getY ( ) ) ) ) ;