# Nested RegEx print_r HTML

Tags: regex

I try to parse html source code.
I have a nested regular expression

**(\˂[0-9a-z\s#-_="]*\˃((?>[^\˂\˃]+)|(?R))*(\˂/[a-z]*\˃)?\s*)*** inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex):

My problem is that I only get 2 levels (the div and table tags).
Is there something wrong in my RegEx?

```
<pre>
<?php
$pattern = '/(\˂[0-9a-z\s#-_="]*\˃((?>[^\˂\˃]+)|(?R))*(\˂\/[a-z]*\˃)?\s*)*/mx';

$subject = <<<EOT
˂div class="post"˃
    ˂table˃
        ˂tbody˃
            ˂tr height="12"˃
                ˂td˃˂/td˃
                ˂td width="20" class="strip" rowspan="5"˃   
                    ˂div class="follow unpublish"˃☆˂/div˃                                   
                    ˂div class="follow report"˃⚐˂/div˃
                ˂/td˃
            ˂/tr˃
        ˂/tbody˃
    ˂/table˃
˂/div˃
EOT;

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
</pre>
```

[Run on phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rk1a-utu6)

Comment: There's this typical [**TONY THE PONY**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) smelling... in short, use a parser, ie `DomDocument` instead.

Comment: Use of regex should be possible for a clean html (no javascript os style, just tags with string attributes). I try to avoid a parser. Once defined, a regex is easier to use then a parser. And can be used on other languages that support nested regex.

Comment: Roses are red, Skies are blue, DOMs are severed by parsers solely.