# Oracle - Removing Parentheses enclosed substring(s)

Tags: regex, oracle

Oracle 12cR1 - I have a web based application I am writing.  I have the need to process a string and remove open/close parentheses and all text within. For example, if my input is

```
This is a (bad) sample, (my) friend
```

the output should be

```
This is a sample, friend
```

I have this working in Javascript.  I need it to work in BOTH javascript and Oracle SQL. The code in Javascript is

```
var s2 = s1.replace(/\([^()]*\)/g, '');
```

When I try to convert this to Oracle SQL, nothing happens, aka my output is exactly the same as my input...

```
select regexp_replace('This is a (bad) sample','/\([^()]*\)/g', '') from dual;
```

In searching, someone posted a different regexp expression, which I tried.  Again, no change in the output.

```
select regexp_replace('This is a (bad) sample','(?<=\()[\d.]+(?=\))', '') from dual;
```

IDEALLY, what I would like is a regular expression that also handles nested parentheses, deleting the entire phrase.

```
This is a ((really) bad) example
```

should return

```
This is a example
```

For nested parentheses, the JavaScript expression matches on the inner most set of parentheses, so I just have to run my code twice, which works.

So in summary, what is an Oracle SQL statement that takes a string, and deletes (ideally nested) parentheses and all text within the parentheses?  Note that there may be multiple sets of parentheses (not necessarily nested) so I need it to remove each occurrence of parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match nested brackets using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
select regexp_replace('This is a (bad) sample, (my) friend','\([^()]*\)', '') from dual
```

See the [online Oracle demo](http://rextester.com/DDDTTF73167)

The regex delimiters that are used in JavaScript regex literals should not be part of the Oracle regex pattern (that is POSIX based).

[image]

If you also want to get rid of optional whitespace before the word, add `\s*` before that pattern:

```
regexp_replace('This is a (bad) sample, (my) friend','\s*\([^()]*\)', '')
                                                      ^^^
```

Where `\s*` matches 0+ whitespace chars.

Note you cannot deal with nested parentheses with Oracle regex as it does not support recursion/balanced constructs.

However, you may handle 2 levels of depth with

```
select regexp_replace(
  'This is a (bad) sample, (my) friend and this is a ((really) bad (and more bad)) example',
  '\s*\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)',
   '') as Result from dual
```

See [another Oracle demo](http://rextester.com/ZUUEF41885) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SIsKKn/2).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*` - 0+ sequences of

  - `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
  - `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)`.

[image]

Comment: That did it!  Thanks

Comment: To handle the double (not nested) parentheses case, you can use this "select regexp_replace('This is a ((very)(really) bad) sample, (my) friend','\s*\(((\([^()]*\))+|[^()])*\)', '') from dual"

Comment: @YomnaFahmy I would unroll that pattern, [`\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/SIsKKn/2). That way, it will be more efficient. However, it will only handle 1- or 2-level nested parentheses, so it is just a workaround for some edge cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your pattern doesn't handle the single parentheses case. You can test it here https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99428

Comment: @YomnaFahmy No need to, I fixed the typo (forgot to put `^` in the first bracket expression), and added to the answer.