# extract text from parenthesis but no parenthesis inside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$$(issues) filter({ createdAt: { $gte: moment(new Date('2018')).endOf('year').toDate() } }) pickBy(createdAt) as(issues)
```

parenthesis inside parenthesis should not match

so the value will only

```
issue
{ createdAt: { $gte: moment(new Date('2018')).endOf('year').toDate() } }
createdAt
issues
```

this match all parenthesis which is wrong

```
\((.+?)\)
```

[image]

Comment: In JS you cannot do this by regex. You will need to use a parser?

Comment: your expression will be  always with the same structure? still pickBy (createdAt) as (issues) at the end? always $$ (issues) at first? still filter the keyword? It can sometimes contain an additional prefix or suffix?

Comment: For this sample data `/\((.*?)\)(?=\s|$)/g` may work with assumption that there is a whitespace or line end after closing `)` See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/m1e5Bt/1

Comment: @Eric

$$(groups) pickBy(parentGroupId, shortName, name) as(groups)
$$(users) pickBy(profile.name) as(users)
$$(issues) pickBy(title, groupId, createdById, createdAt) as(issues)

ref(groups) keyBy(_id) as(groups)
ref(users) keyBy(_id) as(users)
ref(issues) map(groupId = groups.shortname || groups.name, createdById = users.profile.name,  createdAt = @YYYY) as(issues)

pivot rows(createdAt, createdById, groupId)

dict(groups, users)
output(issues)

Comment: i've found that there's recursive pattern but doesn't work with js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: You may find a couple of JS solutions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271017/3832970) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093078/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow kool, i m trying now

Comment: 1) Do you use lodash javascript api?   
2) what is the ultimate goal?   
3) can the problem be solved with lodash? If not, use a Lex analyzer to create an abstract tree, but you must provide a grammar. 3b) Once the tree is built, go through it and recreate what you need.

Comment: yes i mix lodash and mongo db query work together, i don't want to translate all grammar to mongo query pipeline because i still have to operate normal jsobject

Comment: is there any js Lex analyzer easy to use? i have no experience to lex analyzer