# PHP get text within brackets deep

Tags: php, regex

I have text like this between brackets [ and ]:

```
$commands = "[CMD1,[CMD2],[CMD3,[CMD4],[CMD5]]]";
```

and execute with this PHP function:

```
preg_match_all('/\\[(.*?)\\]/', $commands, $matches);
```

And output of index 1 is:

```
array(2) (
    ...
    1 => array(3) (
        0 => string(10) "CMD1,[CMD2"
        1 => string(10) "CMD3,[CMD4"
        2 => string(4) "CMD5"
    )
)
```

however I want to process the deepest one first, output like this:

```
array(2) (
    ...
    1 => array(3) (
        0 => string(4) "CMD5"
        1 => string(4) "CMD4"
        2 => string(4) "CMD3"
        3 => string(4) "CMD2"
        4 => string(4) "CMD1"
    )
)
```

Can preg_match_all do that?

Comment: You may need to write an expression parser to get this behavior.

Comment: Regex is evaluated from left to right. You cannot make it move back and forth. You can get the matches from regex and later do some post processing to get desired result.

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952113/how-can-i-match-nested-brackets-using-regex helps.

Comment: Maybe `preg_match_all('/[^][,]+/', $commands, $matches)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_match_all('/[^][,]+/', $commands, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1KFPqv/1). The `[^][,]+` regex matches one or more occurrences of any char other than `]`, `[` and `,`.

Since the regex engine processes the string (i.e. searched for pattern matches) from left to right, you cannot get the matches in the order you specified in the question. If you want to reverse them, use `rsort`.

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/I1GIo):

```php
$commands = "[CMD1,[CMD2],[CMD3,[CMD4],[CMD5]]]";
if (preg_match_all('/[^][,]+/', $commands, $matches)) {
    $array = $matches[0];
    rsort($array);
    print_r($array);
}
// => Array( [0] => CMD5 [1] => CMD4  [2] => CMD3 [3] => CMD2 [4] => CMD1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code.

```
$commands = "[CMD1,[CMD2],[CMD3,[CMD7],[CMD4],[CMD5]]]";
$array = explode(",", $commands);

array_walk($array, function(&$val, $key){
     $val = trim( trim($val,"]") ,"[");
});

rsort($array);

print_r($array);
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CMD7
    [1] => CMD5
    [2] => CMD4
    [3] => CMD3
    [4] => CMD2
    [5] => CMD1
)
```

Comment: no, CMD? is not shorted number, it can anytext.